# sql query double precision - null >0 not returning any record

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, precision

I am using Postgresql database and I am having a column `invoicehead`. What I do is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM invoicehead WHERE (invamt-collection_amt >= 0)

invamt type = double precision
collection_amt type = double precision
```

**invamt  is having values 100.00, 500.00, 300.00,-250.00 and
collection_amt  having values all null**

So when I do `invamt-collection_amt >= 0` it will be **double precision with value - null**.

I am not getting any values as query result.

**How can make query in such a way that if null should take the effect of zero?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add second condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoicehead 
WHERE invamt-collection_amt >= 0 
   OR (invamt-collection_amt) IS NULL
```

Alternatively you can change `NULL` with `0` using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoicehead 
WHERE COALESCE(invamt,0) - COALESCE(collection_amt,0) >= 0
```

`NULL` value cannot be directly compared with other values using comparison operators like `=,<>,<,>, <=,>=,...`

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` or `IF` condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoicehead 
WHERE (COALESCE(invamt,0) - COALESCE(collection_amt,0)) >= 0
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoicehead 
WHERE (IF(invamt IS NOT NULL, invamt ,0) - IF(collection_amt IS NOT NULL, collection_amt,0)) >= 0
```